# some questions about Extjs 4.0.7

Tags: dynamic, extjs, gridpanel

I want to implement a dynamic column in grid panel, how can I do it? I used Extjs 4.0.7:

```
var result = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
store.model.setFields(result.fields);
grid.reconfigure(store, result.columns);
store.loadRawData(result.data, false);
```

The method `setFields()` doesn't exist in version 4.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({fields: result.fields, data: result.data})

grid.reconfigure(store, result.columns})
```

The fields config on Store has always behaved this way, with the ability to pass in fields instead of a model.  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-fields